# Крашится слайдер SliderSlick

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Не пойму в чём причина крушения слайдера на [этом сайте](https://velobike.github.io/), имеется ввиду появление внизу отступа или картинки
Использовал `bootstrap3`, `sliderslick`. 
Появляется через несколько нажатий (до 3) на стрелку и после этого наводишь на товар, то получается тот хаос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.slikslid').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
});
```

```css
.mag_posit1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
}

.mag_posit1:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
}

.mag_posit:hover {
  border: 2px inset black;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.vidor_diag {
  font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  display: none;
}

.mag_posit:hover .vidor_diag {
  display: block;
}

.sales {
  background: url(img/sales.png) no-repeat;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

sales_txt {
  font-family: OpenSans-SemiBold;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  position: absolute;
}

.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.rating>span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 0.8em;
}

.rating>span:hover:before,
.rating>span:hover~span:before {
  content: "\2605";
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 pull-left" style="position: relative;">
    <img src="img/1_top.png" />
    <a href="#" style="position: absolute; margin-top: -25px; margin-left: 70px;color:#fff;text-decoration:underline;">СМОТРЕТЬ МОДЕЛИ</a>
  </div>
  <div class="cod-md-6 pull-left" style="position: relative;">
    <img src="img/2__toop.png" style="margin-left: -3px;" />
    <a href="#" style="position: absolute;margin-top: -25px; color:#fff;margin-left: 215px;text-decoration:underline;">СМОТРЕТЬ МОДЕЛИ</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 pull-left" style="position: relative;">
    <img src="img/ibert.png" height="161" width="280" style="margin-left: -13px;" />
    <a href="#" style="position: absolute;color:#fff;margin-top: -25px;margin-left: 60px;text-decoration:underline;">СМОТРЕТЬ МОДЕЛИ</a>
    <img src="img/tigger.png" height="161" width="270" style="margin-left: -13px; margin-top: 3px;" />
    <a href="#" style="position: absolute;color:#fff;margin-top: 140px;margin-left: -210px;text-decoration:underline;">СМОТРЕТЬ МОДЕЛИ</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center txt_header">НОВИНКИ</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="prev-pos">
      <p style="font-size: 20px;color:#000;margin-bottom: 200px;position: absolute;margin-left: -15px;">
        <img src="img/prev.png" style="margin-top: 170px; margin-left: -10px;">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="next-pos" style="float: right;">
      <p style="font-size: 20px;color:#000;margin-bottom: 200px;position: absolute;margin-left: 5px;">
        <img src="img/next.png" style="margin-top: 170px;margin-left: 10px;">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="slikslid">
      <div class="col-md-3 mag_posit" style="position: relative;">
        <a href="#" class="mag_posit1">
          <img class="sales" src="img/sales.png" />
          <div class="sales_txt">-15%</div>
          <img src="img/bike.png" alt="bike">
          <div class="rating">
            <span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span>
          </div>
          <div class="time_pos">
            <button class="btn time_pos_bt">new</button>
          </div>
          <div class="name_bike">
            <span>Bergamont Vitox 26</span>
          </div>
          <div class="type_bike">
            <span>Велосипед</span>
          </div>
          <div class="started">
            <span>12096</span>
          </div>
          <div class="price">
            <span>10519 грн.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="point">
            <span style="font-family:OpenSans-Italic;">+</span>1200 BikeПоинтов
          </div>
          <span class="fa fa-heart" style="margin-left: 10px;">
       <span class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="margin-left: 5px;">
       </span></span>
        </a>
        <button class="btn btn_baces">В КОРЗИНУ</button>
        <div class="vidor_diag">
          <select class="form-control" style="margin-top: 20px;">
           <option>16” (160 - 170 см)</option>
           <option>16” (160 - 170 см)</option>
       </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вставьте код сюда.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko слайдера?

Comment: Да, код, который воспроизводит проблему.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Я скинул, если правильно понял.

Comment: Тут можно сделать сниппет, который запустится прямо на этой странице - сделайте лучше его. Ну и CSS для слайдера точно понадобится еще.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko можно ссылку на сниппет, в первый раз слышу о нем. CSS щас добавлю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko СSS добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ух, я когда код ваш увидел, сильно удивился. 
Убирайте оттуда классы бутстрапа, ведь slick slider и так адаптивный, более того, адаптив настраиваемый.

- Заходите на офф. сайт http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
- Далее идете в раздел «Responsive Display».
- Делайте как нужно. Коротко, просто при определенном разрешении экрана(breakpoint) меняете количество отображаемых слайдов на экране(slidesToShow).

---

**Итого**: Bootstrap 3 в данном случае совсем ненужен, адаптив настраивайте через настройки Slick slider. Будут проблемы/вопросы, пишите.